# Enabling Macros in Excel using GemBox 3.1 API

Tags: c#, excel, gembox-spreadsheet

Well recently having a problem with GemBox.SpreadSheet 3.1. Right now the program will write an excel file, but when opening the file it will attempt to open the file saying "Excel found unreadable content" then asks yes or no if you wanna try to recover the document. Click yes, it then says "The file is a macro-free file, but contains macro-enabled content".

However, when the program makes different files without the Macros, it does not say it is corrupt and works just fine.

So my question is, How do you enable the Macro content using GemBox API? Or is there just bad coding somewhere?

EDIT:
I figured out that the program was saving the wrong extension.

Comment: I figured out that that in order for Macro-enabled content, the file needs to be stored in XLSM, NOT XLSX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that that in order for Macro-enabled content, the file needs to be stored in XLSM, NOT XLSX!